# error: unrecognised directive [ORG]

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, dosbox

I was trying to write a boot-loader to use in dos-box
I wrote the following code

```
[BITS 16]   ;tell the assembler that its a 16 bit code
[ORG 0x7C00]    ;Origin, tell the assembler that where the code will
;be in memory after it is been loaded

JMP $       ;infinite loop

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;fill the rest of sector with 0
DW 0xAA55           ; add boot signature at the end of bootloader
```

I was trying to assemble it using nasm by the following command

```
nasm -f elf myfile.asm
```

Then I see that error

> error: unrecognised directive [ORG]

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the version of nasm is 2.10.09

Comment: When using _ELF_ the _[ORG]_ directive doesn't apply. With _ELF_ You set the origin point using the linker when generating the final binary. If you don't want _ELF_ and want a straight binary use `nasm -f bin` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Copied from @MichaelPetch in the comment section so this question has an answer:

> When using *ELF* the *[ORG]* directive doesn't apply. With *ELF*, you set the origin point by using the linker when generating the final binary. If you don't want *ELF* and want a straight binary, use `nasm -f bin myfile.asm` instead.

Comment: Copied from the @MichaelPetch in the comment section so this question has an answer.