# Compile an asm bootloader with external c code

Tags: gcc, x86, nasm, inline-assembly, bootloader

I write a boot loader in asm and want to add some compiled C code in my project.

I created a test function here:

**test.c**

```
__asm__(".code16\n");

void print_str() {
    __asm__ __volatile__("mov $'A' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("mov $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x10\n");
}
```

And here is the asm code (the boot loader):

**hw.asm**

```
[org 0x7C00]
[BITS 16]
[extern print_str] ;nasm tip

start:
mov ax, 0
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7C00


mov si, name
call print_string

mov al, ' '
int 10h

mov si, version
call print_string

mov si, line_return
call print_string

call print_str ;call function

mov si, welcome
call print_string

jmp mainloop

mainloop:
mov si, prompt
call print_string

mov di, buffer
call get_str

mov si, buffer
cmp byte [si], 0
je mainloop

mov si, buffer
;call print_string
mov di, cmd_version
call strcmp
jc .version

jmp mainloop

.version:
mov si, name
call print_string

mov al, ' '
int 10h

mov si, version
call print_string

mov si, line_return
call print_string
jmp mainloop

name db 'MOS', 0
version db 'v0.1', 0
welcome db 'Developped by Marius Van Nieuwenhuyse', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
prompt db '>', 0
line_return db 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
buffer times 64 db 0

cmd_version db 'version', 0

%include "functions/print.asm"
%include "functions/getstr.asm"
%include "functions/strcmp.asm"

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I need to call the c function like a simple asm function
Without the extern and the call `print_str`, the asm script boot in VMWare.

I tried to compile with:

```
nasm -f elf32
```

***But i can't call org 0x7C00***

Comment: Use `nasm -f bin hw.asm`, thanks for [Michael-Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch) comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720481/error-unrecognised-directive-org

Comment: You can find it out by simply search your assembler output on Google.

Comment: @EsmaeelE : That won't work because he wants to link the two files together. Can't do that with `-f bin` but you can drop the `org 0x7c00` and then assemble with `nasm -f elf32 hw.asm -o hw.o` and then use the linker specifying the VMA with `-Ttext=0x7c00` (or use a linker script).

Comment: You'd really need a linker script to ensure everything was placed properly into the output file for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i tested and i have a question : Now, ld is placing test.o after the content of hw.o, the 0x55AA is before the test.o code. In my test it's printing MOS v0.1 and a line return. (stopping at the call of the c function).
Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah see my followup comment. You'll need to use a linker script to position to sections in the output file and use the linker script to place the boot signature rather than putting it in hw.asm

Comment: Yea it work !! Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Compiling & Linking NASM and GCC Code

This question has a more complex answer than one might believe, although it is possible. Can the first stage of a bootloader (the original 512 bytes that get loaded at physical address 0x07c00) make a call into a *C* function? Yes, but it requires rethinking how you build your project.

For this to work you can no longer us `-f bin` with *NASM*. This also means you can't use the `org 0x7c00` to tell the assembler what address the code expects to start from. You'll need to do this through a linker (either us *LD* directly or *GCC* for linking). Since the linker will lay things out in memory we can't rely on placing the boot sector signature `0xaa55` in our output file. We can get the linker to do that for us.

The first problem you will discover is that the default linker scripts used internally by *GCC* don't lay things out the way we want. We'll need to create our own. Such a linker script will have to set the origin point (Virtual Memory Address aka VMA) to 0x7c00, place the code from your assembly file before the data and place the boot signature at offset 510 in the file. I'm not going to write a tutorial on Linker scripts. The [Binutils Documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts) contains almost everything you need to know about linker scripts.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386");
/* We define an entry point to keep the linker quiet. This entry point
 * has no meaning with a bootloader in the binary image we will eventually
 * generate. Bootloader will start executing at whatever is at 0x07c00 */
ENTRY(start);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : {
        /* Place the code in hw.o before all other code */
        hw.o(.text);
        *(.text);
    }

    /* Place the data after the code */
    .data : SUBALIGN(2) {
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata*);
    }

    /* Place the boot signature at LMA/VMA 0x7DFE */
    .sig 0x7DFE : {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }

    /* Place the uninitialised data in the area after our bootloader
     * The BIOS only reads the 512 bytes before this into memory */
    .bss : SUBALIGN(4) {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(COMMON);
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __bss_end = .;
    }
    __bss_sizeb = SIZEOF(.bss);

    /* Remove sections that won't be relevant to us */
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame);
        *(.comment);
    }
}
```

This script should create an *ELF* executable that can be converted to a flat binary file with *OBJCOPY*. We could have output as a binary file directly but I separate the two processes out in the event I want to include debug information in the *ELF* version for debug purposes.

Now that we have a linker script we must remove the `ORG 0x7c00` and the boot signature. For simplicity sake we'll try to get the following code (`hw.asm`) to work:

```
extern print_str
global start
bits 16

section .text
start:
xor ax, ax         ; AX = 0
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7C00

call print_str     ; call function

/* Halt the processor so we don't keep executing code beyond this point */
cli
hlt
```

You can include all your other code, but this sample will still demonstrate the basics of calling into a *C* function.

Assume the code above you can now generate the *ELF* object from `hw.asm` producing `hw.o` using this command:

```
nasm -f elf32 hw.asm -o hw.o
```

You compile each *C* file with something like:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c kmain.c -o kmain.o
```

I placed the *C* code you had into a file called `kmain.c` . The command above will generate `kmain.o`. I noticed you aren't using a cross compiler so you'll want to use `-fno-PIE` to ensure we don't generate relocatable code. `-ffreestanding` tells GCC the *C* standard library may not exist, and `main` may not be the program entry point. You'd compile each *C* file in the same way.

To link this code to a final executable and then produce a flat binary file that can be booted we do this:

```
ld -melf_i386 --build-id=none -T link.ld kmain.o hw.o -o kernel.elf
objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
```

You specify all the object files to link with the *LD* command. The *LD* command above will produce a 32-bit ELF executable called `kernel.elf`. This file can be useful in the future for debugging purposes. Here we use *OBJCOPY* to convert `kernel.elf` to a binary file called `kernel.bin`. `kernel.bin` can be used as a bootloader image.

You should be able to run it with *QEMU* using this command:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda kernel.bin
```

When run it may look like:

[image]

You'll notice the letter `A` appears on the last line. This is what we'd expect from the `print_str` code.

---

### GCC Inline Assembly is Hard to Get Right

If we take your example code in the question:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("mov $'A' , %al\n");
__asm__ __volatile__("mov $0x0e, %ah\n");
__asm__ __volatile__("int $0x10\n");
```

The compiler is free to reorder these `__asm__` statements if it wanted to. The `int $0x10` could appear before the MOV instructions. If you want these 3 lines to be output in this exact order you can combine them into one like this:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("mov $'A' , %al\n\t"
                     "mov $0x0e, %ah\n\t"
                     "int $0x10");
```

These are basic assembly statements. It's not required to specify `__volatile__`on them as they are already [implicitly volatile](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm), so it has no effect. From the original poster's answer it is clear they want to eventually use variables in `__asm__` blocks. This is doable with [extended inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) (the instruction string is followed by a colon `:` followed by constraints.):

With extended asm you can read and write C variables from assembler and perform jumps from assembler code to C labels. Extended asm syntax uses colons (‘:’) to delimit the operand parameters after the assembler template:

> ```
> asm [volatile] ( AssemblerTemplate
>                 : OutputOperands 
>                 [ : InputOperands
>                 [ : Clobbers ] ])
> ```

This answer isn't a tutorial on inline assembly. The general rule of thumb is that one [should not use inline assembly unless you have to](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm). Inline assembly done wrong can create hard to track bugs or have unusual side effects. Unfortunately doing 16-bit interrupts in *C* pretty much requires it, or you write the entire function in assembly (ie: NASM).

This is an example of a `print_chr` function that take a nul terminated string and prints each character out one by one using [Int 10h/ah=0ah](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm):

```
#include <stdint.h>
__asm__(".code16gcc\n");

void print_str(char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        /* AH=0x0e, AL=char to print, BH=page, BL=fg color */
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("int $0x10"
                              :
                              : "a" ((0x0e<<8) | *str++),
                                "b" (0x0000));
    }
}
```

`hw.asm` would be modified to look like this:

```
push welcome
call print_str ;call function
```

The idea when this is assembled/compiled (using the commands in the first section of this answer) and run is that it print out the `welcome` message. Unfortunately it will almost never work, and may even crash some emulators like *QEMU*.

---

### code16 is Almost Useless and Should Not be Used

In the last section we learn that a simple function that takes a parameter ends up not working and may even crash an emulator like *QEMU*. The main problem is that the `__asm__(".code16\n");` statement really doesn't work well with the code generated by *GCC*. The [Binutils AS documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002d16bit.html) says:

> ‘.code16gcc’ provides experimental support for generating 16-bit code from gcc, and differs from ‘.code16’ in that ‘call’, ‘ret’, ‘enter’, ‘leave’, ‘push’, ‘pop’, ‘pusha’, ‘popa’, ‘pushf’, and ‘popf’ instructions default to 32-bit size. This is so that the stack pointer is manipulated in the same way over function calls, allowing access to function parameters at the same stack offsets as in 32-bit mode. ‘.code16gcc’ also automatically adds address size prefixes where necessary to use the 32-bit addressing modes that gcc generates.

`.code16gcc` is what you really need to be using, not `.code16`. This force GNU assembler on the back end to emit address and operand prefixes on certain instructions so that the addresses and operands are treated as 4 bytes wide, and not 2 bytes.

The hand written code in *NASM* doesn't know it will be calling *C* instructions, nor does *NASM* have a directive like `.code16gcc`. You'll need to modify the assembly code to push 32-bit values on to the stack in real mode. You will also need to override the `call` instruction so that the return address needs to be treated as a 32-bit value, not 16-bit. This code:

```
push welcome
call print_str ;call function
```

Should be:

```
    jmp 0x0000:setcs
setcs:
    cld
    push dword welcome
    call dword print_str ;call function
```

*GCC* has a requirement that the direction flag be cleared before calling any *C* function. I added the *CLD* instruction to the top of the assembly code to make sure this is the case. *GCC* code also needs to have *CS* to 0x0000 to work properly. The *FAR JMP* does just that.

You can also drop the `__asm__(".code16gcc\n");` on modern *GCC* that supports the `-m16` option. `-m16` automatically places a `.code16gcc` into the file that is being compiled.

Since *GCC* also uses the full 32-bit stack pointer it is a good idea to initialize *ESP* with 0x7c00, not just *SP*. Change `mov sp, 0x7C00` to `mov esp, 0x7C00`. This ensures the full 32-bit stack pointer is 0x7c00.

The modified `kmain.c` code should now look like:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void print_str(char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        /* AH=0x0e, AL=char to print, BH=page, BL=fg color */
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("int $0x10"
                              :
                              : "a" ((0x0e<<8) | *str++),
                                "b" (0x0000));
    }
}
```

and `hw.asm`:

```
extern print_str
global start
bits 16

section .text
start:
    xor ax, ax            ; AX = 0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov esp, 0x7C00
    jmp 0x0000:setcs      ; Set CS to 0
setcs:
    cld                   ; GCC code requires direction flag to be cleared 

    push dword welcome
    call dword print_str  ; call function
    cli
    hlt

section .data
welcome db 'Developped by Marius Van Nieuwenhuyse', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
```

These commands can be build the bootloader with:

```
gcc -fno-PIC -ffreestanding -m16 -c kmain.c -o kmain.o 
ld -melf_i386 --build-id=none -T link.ld kmain.o hw.o -o kernel.elf
objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
```

When run with `qemu-system-i386 -fda kernel.bin` it should look simialr to:

[image]

---

### In Most Cases GCC Produces Code that Requires 80386+

There are number of disadvantages to *GCC* generated code using `.code16gcc`:

- ES=DS=CS=SS must be 0
- Code must fit in the first 64kb
- *GCC* code has no understanding of 20-bit segment:offset addressing.
- For anything but the most trivial *C* code, GCC doesn't generate code that can run on a 286/186/8086. It runs in real mode but it uses 32-bit operands and addressing not available on processors earlier than 80386.
- If you want to access memory locations above the first 64kb then you need to be in [**Unreal Mode**(big)](http://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode#Big_Unreal_Mode) before calling into *C* code.

If you want to produce real 16-bit code from a more modern *C* compiler I recommend [**OpenWatcom C**](http://www.openwatcom.org/)

- The inline assembly is not as powerful as *GCC*
- The inline assembly syntax is different but it is easier to use and less error prone than *GCC*'s inline assembly.
- Can generate code that will run on antiquated 8086/8088 processors.
- Understands 20-bit segment:offset real mode addressing and supports the concept of far and huge pointers.
- `wlink` the Watcom linker can produce basic flat binary files usable as a bootloader.

---

### Zero Fill the BSS Section

The BIOS boot sequence doesn't guarantee that memory is actually zero. This causes a potential problem for the zero initialized region *BSS*. Before calling into *C* code for the first time the region should be zero filled by our assembly code. The linker script I originally wrote defines a symbol `__bss_start` that is the offset of the *BSS* memory and `__bss_sizeb` is the size in bytes. Using this info you can use the *STOSB* instruction to easily zero fill it. At the top of `hw.asm` you can add:

```
extern __bss_sizeb
extern __bss_start
```

And after the *CLD* instruction and before calling any *C* code you can do the zero fill this way:

```
; Zero fill the BSS section
mov cx, __bss_sizeb       ; Size of BSS computed in linker script
mov di, __bss_start       ; Start of BSS defined in linker script
rep stosb                 ; AL still zero, Fill memory with zero
```

---

### Other Suggestions

To reduce the bloat of the code generated by the compiler it can be useful to use `-fomit-frame-pointer`. Compiling with `-Os` can optimize for space (rather than speed). We have limited space (512 bytes) for the initial code loaded by the BIOS so these optimizations can be beneficial. The command line for compiling could appear as:

```
gcc -fno-PIC -fomit-frame-pointer -ffreestanding -m16 -Os -c kmain.c -o kmain.o
```

Answer (score 2):

> I write a boot loader in asm and want to add some compiled C code in my project.

Then you need to use a 16-bit x86 compiler, such as [OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/).

**GCC cannot safely build real-mode code**, as it is unaware of some important features of the platform, including memory segmentation. Inserting the `.code16` directive will make the compiler generate incorrect output. Despite appearing in many tutorials, this piece of advice is simply incorrect, and should not be used.

Comment: What I agree with though is that using GCC for doing bootloader code is not preferable unless you accept the limitations and really know what you are doing. Openwatcom would be my preference as well since it will generate code that can target even an early 8086 processor and understands near/far/huge pointers and understands real mode segmentation. The inline assembly is reasonably easy to pick up but does differ from GCC (minor learning curve). I also use to recommend the third party JLOC linker if targeting bootloaders written with OpenWatcom.

Answer (score -3):

First i want to express how to link C compiled code with assembled file.

I put together some Q/A in SO and reach to this.

***C code:***

**func.c**

```
//__asm__(".code16gcc\n");when we use eax, 32 bit reg we cant use this as truncate 
//problem

#include <stdio.h>
int  x = 0;



int madd(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}



void mexit(){
      __asm__ __volatile__("mov $0, %ebx\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("mov $1, %eax \n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x80\n");
}


char* tmp;

///how to direct use of arguments in asm command
void print_str(int a,  char* s){

      x = a;
        __asm__("mov x, %edx\n");//  ;third argument: message length

        tmp = s;
        __asm__("mov tmp, %ecx\n");//  ;second argument: pointer to message to write

        __asm__("mov $1, %ebx\n");//first argument: file handle (stdout)
    __asm__("mov $4, %eax\n");//system call number (sys_write)


   __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x80\n");//call kernel

}


void mtest(){
    printf("%s\n", "Hi");
    //putchar('a');//why not work
}


///gcc -c func.c -o func
```

***Assembly code:***

**hello.asm**

```
extern  mtest
extern  printf
extern  putchar
extern  print_str
extern  mexit
extern  madd

section .text                   ;section declaration

                                ;we must export the entry point to the ELF linker or
    global  _start              ;loader. They conventionally recognize _start as their
                                      ;entry point. Use ld -e foo to override the default.

_start:
                                ;write our string to stdout         

    push msg
        push len
        call print_str;


        call  mtest                                 ;print "Hi"; call printf inside a void function



                                                                ; use add inside func.c

        push 5
        push 10                                                         
        call madd;              
                                                                ;direct call of <stdio.h> printf()
        push  eax
    push  format
    call  printf;                           ;printf(format, eax)




        call mexit;                                     ;exit to OS


section .data                   ;section declaration
format db "%d", 10, 0
msg db      "Hello, world!",0xa ;our dear string
len equ     $ - msg             ;length of our dear string



; nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello

;Link two files 
;ld hello func -o hl -lc -I /lib/ld-linux.so.2
; ./hl run code

;chain to assemble, compile, Run
;;   gcc -c func.c -o func && nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello && ld hello func -o hl -lc -I /lib/ld-linux.so.2 && echo &&./hl
```

***Chain commands for assemble, compile and Run***

> `gcc -c func.c -o func && nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello && ld hello func -o hl -lc -I /lib/ld-linux.so.2 && echo && ./hl`

***Edit[toDO]***

- Write boot loader code instead of this version
- Some explanation on how ld, gcc, nasm works.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you writing a real mode bootloader or a Linux application? The code in your question was for a bootloader but this answer is Linux specific.

Comment: @MichaelPetch i Will add bootloader, yes this is linux app

Comment: I'm confused. If you write a bootloader in real mode you won't be able to make Linux calls.

Comment: This type of code is frowned upon `__asm__("mov x, %edx\n");` Using variable names inside basic assembler will only have a chance to work with global variables (not ones on the stack) and may go through name mangling. You should pass variables into assembly using GCC's extended inline assembly templates.

Comment: From the [GCC inline assembly documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)  _Accessing data from C programs without using input/output operands (such as by using global symbols directly from the assembler template) may not work as expected._