# c bootloader passing function parameters doesn't work right

Tags: c, gcc, parameters, x86-16, bootloader

I have a basic bootloader in c, but when I try to pass a parameter to a function, it doesn't work quite right.
The following code doesn't work:

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("call main\n");

void main(){
    putchar('X');
    while(1){}
}

void putchar(char c){
    __asm__("movb %0, %%al\n" : : "r"(c));
    __asm__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__("int $0x10\n");
}
```

It should print out an X, but instead it just moves the cursor forward as if printing a space.

The following code works because it doesn't pass the character as a parameter:

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("call main\n");

char c;

void main(){
    c = 'X';
    putchar();
    while(1){}
}

void putchar(){
    __asm__("movb %0, %%al\n" : : "r"(c));
    __asm__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__("int $0x10\n");
}
```

Can someone explain why it isn't working?

Comment: I don't think this is your problem but putchar is a built-in function

Comment: @TheAschr : Not when you build code with -ffreestanding which he must be since this is a bootloader.

Comment: You will have serious issues using `.code16`. .`code16` will have serious problems especially when passing parameters. You'll want to use `.code16gcc`. A recent question had some similarities to this one. I wrote this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276625/3857942 . You may wish to read the sections _GCC Inline Assembly is Hard to Get Right_ and _`.code16` is Almost Useless and Should Not be Used_

Comment: Did you happen to follow a tutorial on Codeproject? More importantly can you tell me the `gcc` command line you use to compile the `.c` file?

Comment: @MichaelPetch : Yes, I did use some of the tutorial on codeproject. Here's my compiler command: gcc -m32 -c -Os -march=i686 -ffreestanding -Wall -o kernel.o kernel.c -Iinclude

Comment: There is a lot wrong in that tutorial but the primary one that is causing issues with parameters is that `.code16` is the wrong directive. It should be `.code16gcc`

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the fact that it was being passed as a parameter, but rather, I was using the assembly wrongly. The following code works:

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("call main\n");

void main(){
    putchar('!');
    while(1){}
}

void putchar(char c){
    __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x10" : : "a"(0x0e00 | c), "b"(0x0007));
}
```

Comment: The reason this isn't the answer is because you happened to get luck that the optimizer inlined the functions and didn't use the stack to pass parameters. To prove this will break if the function isn't inlined and the paramater `X` is passed via the stack one can modify this line of code `void putchar(char c){` to be `void __attribute__((noinline)) putchar(char c){` . Now if you build this it should fail. Effectively you got lucky the code worked thanks to the optimiser.You would also find that if you change the _GCC_ parameter `-Os` to `-O0` to disable optimizations it will also fail.