# Compiling C to ELF32 on Windows

Tags: c, windows, assembly, gcc, elf

I am trying to compile a C program to ELF format on Windows, so I tried to do several things:

1. Compiled with MinGW `gcc -Wall -c test.c -o test.o`, but got no test.o as an output
2. Downloaded https://github.com/nativeos/i386-elf-toolchain/releases (the 32 bit version), and compiled with `"[...]/i386-elf-gcc" -c test.c -o test.o`, but I got the error `i386-elf-gcc/libexec/gcc/i386-elf/5.2.0/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

What I'm trying to do is to follow this tutorial here: https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial, but I'm stuck on the part of making the actual link between Assembly and C. I'm well aware of the fact that this tutorial is made for Linux, not Windows, but I just... Let's just say I'm having trouble using Linux.

I don't know what files are needed to resolve my issue, so here's:

1. kernel.c

```c
void my_function() {
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

2. kernel_entry.asm

```
[bits 32]
[extern main]
call main
jmp $
```

3. boot.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]

kernel_offset equ 0x1000

    mov [bootDrive], dl

    mov bp, 0x9000
    mov sp, bp

    call switch_to_pm

    call BEGIN_PM

    jmp $

%include "gdt_init.asm"
%include "switch_32.asm"

bootDrive db 0

[bits 32]
BEGIN_PM:
    call clear_screen
    call kernel_offset

    mov ebx, errorMSG
    call print_string_pm

    jmp $

%include "io/clear.asm"
%include "io/print.asm"


errorMSG db "Something went terribly wrong. Restart the PC to fix it", 0

; bootsector
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

The other files are a near copy-paste, so I didn't think it is necessary to include them

Comment: The cross compiler issue will be the build tools and not the code. Did you follow the advice in the installation instructions including having things on your path correctly, and it suggested in some cases you may have to copy all the files from two directories into one?

Comment: As for compiling with MinGW something seems wrong if there was no object file output. Was there an error message? You mention `test.c` maybe you meant `kernel.c`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah, I meant kernel.c, also the compilation with GCC displays no errors, as well as no output. Also I haven't followed the advice (which I probably should have done, before asking on Stackoverflow and what I'm going to do)

Comment: @MichaelPetch It didn't work; I put all of the stuff in a single folder, as well as the PATH thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's a little complicated, so buckle up.

First, I've used NASM and MinGW. Here's a list of my following actions:

1. Assembled bootsector.asm as normal (`nasm bootsect.asm -o bootset.o`)
2. Assembled kernel_entry.asm with `nasm kernel_entry.asm -f elf32 -o kernel_entry.o`,after
3. Compiled kernel.c with `gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc`
4. Linked kernel_entry.o and kernel.tmp with `ld -m i386pe -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o`
5. Transformed kernel.tmp to bin with `objcopy -O binary -j .text  kernel.tmp kernel.bin`
6. Merged together bootsect.o and kernel.bin with `type bootsect.o kernel.bin > drive.bin`

Comment: Including / extracting only the `.text` section with `objcopy` is going to be problematic if you ever use any static data (`.data` or `.bss`) or constant (`.rodata`) like string literals.  Better to use a linker script to tell `ld` where to put stuff in a binary.  e.g. @MichaelPetch's example here: [Compile an asm bootloader with external c code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47249699)